# Merg foreach and if(regex) in one statement

Tags: regex, perl

Is there any chance to do

```
 foreach my $elements(keys %my_hash){
     if($element =~ /some_expression/{
         do something;
     }
 }
```

in one statement like

```
foreach my $elements (keys %my_hash) =~ /some expression/{
    do something;
}
```

Comment: Look up the map function

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html

Comment: @user1717259 `map` won't help; you need `grep`. `map` transforms every element whereas `grep` filters elements.

Comment: `next if $elements !~ /some_expression/;` might be better regarding readability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach my $elements (grep /some_expression/, keys %my_hash) {
    do something;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `grep` builtin:

```
for my $element (grep /some_expression/, keys %my_hash) {
  do_something();
}
```